# Spring Boot 2.1 MVC Logging

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Upgrading Spring Boot 2.1.x from 2.0.x, not logging MVC mapping logs..

**Spring Boot 2.0.x** logs MVC Mapping at INFO level, it was very convinient and easily identifiable logs.

```
**Spring Boot 2.0.x**
2019-01-24 20:10:11.165  INFO  [           main]  s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  Mapped "{[/mapping2],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.test.controller.ControllerClass.method2()
2019-01-24 20:10:11.167  INFO  [           main]  s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  Mapped "{[/mapping1],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.test.controller.ControllerClass.method1()
```

As per Spring Boot 2.1.x documentation, 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#logging-refinements

There are no Info logs for MVC Mapping. Only summary logged as debug log. 
We have to update level to TRACE to get more details.

```
**Spring Boot 2.0.x**
2019-01-24 20:16:08.549 TRACE 2516 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
    c.t.c.ControllerClass:
    {GET /mapping1}: method1()
    {GET /mapping2}: method2()
2019-01-24 20:16:08.554 TRACE 2516 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
    o.s.b.a.w.s.e.BasicErrorController:
    { /error}: error(HttpServletRequest)
    { /error, produces [text/html]}: errorHtml(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)
2019-01-24 20:16:08.560 DEBUG 2516 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 4 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2019-01-24 20:16:08.584 DEBUG 2516 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Detected 0 mappings in 'beanNameHandlerMapping'
```

By updating web log level to DEBUG or TRACE, We get more debug logs from Spring Web and they are not useful always. Unless, TRACE level, they are not much meaningful.

```
2019-01-24 20:39:59.767 TRACE 2516 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/mapping1", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-01-24 20:39:59.768 TRACE 2516 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public java.lang.String com.test.controller.ControllerClass.method1()
2019-01-24 20:39:59.769 TRACE 2516 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: []
2019-01-24 20:39:59.771 DEBUG 2516 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/html', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [text/plain, */*, text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-01-24 20:39:59.771 TRACE 2516 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing ["Method1"]
2019-01-24 20:39:59.776 TRACE 2516 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2019-01-24 20:39:59.777 DEBUG 2516 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
```

Is it possible to get Spring log information ? and How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spring Boot 2.1 version to get RequestMappingHandlerMapping log on console try add

`logging.level.org.springframework.web=trace`

on `application.properties` file

It worked for me